# Does the primary key value of the user ID via Facebook API will be changed/not changed after login or later?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We are making a site for now and will have the Facebook Signup/login API.
When we try to login via Facebook API, below is what we've got:

id,
first_name,
gender,
last_name,
link,
locale,
name
timezone,
updated_time,
verified,

However, the question is, we are not sure that whether the primary key value of the user ID from Facebook API is changed or not after re-login OR after a certain period of time.

Please advise. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will stay the same before and after re-login and over all time, and be individual per App.